# Select last 2 record against record ID in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I want to know if there is a query for selecting last two inserted records against record ID.

For example we can select only 1 top record by using this query:

```
select max(colName) from tableName
```

But what query could be for this:

```
select "Last two records of" colName where id = 1
```

so if we have 100 records in the table and we have 10 records against id number 1, then we should get the last two inserted records against the id number 1.

Please help me if anybody understood my question.

Note: id is not unique key OR primary key in the table from where I want to get the record.

Comment: top 2 order by id desc?

Comment: SQL Table represents unordered sets until you specify them with explicitly order by clause. If there is no certain ordering column, you can never determine which are 2 last records.

Answer (score 1):

Script should be something like below-

```
SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM tableName
WHERE id = 1
ORDER BY colName DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
select colName from tablename where id in (x,x-1)
```

Assuming you are using auto increment for the primary key

Comment: x would be the result of the select max(), but @mkRabbani has a better answer above, forgot in sql-server you can do select top x from. So upvote him and someone mark it as correct so we can move on.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the column, `created_at` you can do something like

```
select * from table where id = 1 order by created_at desc limit 2
```

that should give you the most recent inserted elements. Are you using postgres, mysql, oracle?

Comment: @graned I am using MS SQL server, I want to get the record of specific column. Like I have a column named "Complaints" so I wants the last two complaints against same patient ID to show them in rdlc report viewer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top (2) * from <myTable> where id = 1 order by id DESC
```

This will return last 2 inseted rows where Id = 1

Comment: And if there are 10 records with ID = 1 how are you sure that you get the two last inserted records with ID = 1?